# How to use Facebook Page tokens using javascript?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Trying to get deleting comments going using the javascript SDK of Facebook. But I don't understand where to put the actuall page token in the script.

The PHP one makes sense.

```
try {

$response = $fb->delete(
   '/{comment-id}',
    array (),
   '{access-token}'
);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
```

But the javascript one looks like this.

```
FB.api(
"/{comment-id}",
"DELETE",
function (response) {
  if (response && !response.error) {
    /* handle the result */
  }
}
);
```

So if I want to do the same using javascript, where would the actual Page Token go?

EDIT:

I did find some reference to this.

```
 FB.api(
   '/' + commentID,
'DELETE',
{access_token: 'your-page-token'},
function (response) {
    console.log(response, commentID);
    if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */

    }
}
);
```

But it gives me the same result when entering my page token.

Comment: looks correct, but what is the result exactly? did you debug your token?

Comment: Well I generate it using the graph tool. But the result when I run the above code is always "Publishing comments through the API is only available for page access tokens"

I don't know if this guide is accurate, but at step 19 it says:

"19) Copy and Paste this token into the field labeled "Facebook Access Token" on the plugin's Settings page."

And I don't seem to find where to do this. Could this be it?

https://smashballoon.com/custom-facebook-feed/page-token/

Comment: what plugin? the error message is quite clear, are you 100% sure you are using a page token of the page where that comment got posted? again, debug the togen before using it: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention I did debug it here 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Not sure what you mean by plugin. I created my own app and made everything mostly using javascript. The debugger does say that it is of Type: User. Is that wrong?

Comment: yes, of course. it needs to be a page token, that´s what the error message tells you.

Comment: Allright but that's what I don't really get. Should I not create it using the tool? I select the specific page from the drop down and click "get acess token". Is this not the way?

Thank you for your answears by the way!

Comment: I also followed the guide in the previous link I sent.

Comment: i just read that article...you should NEVER enter any token on some random page. you can just create a page token in the graph api explorer directly, just take a closer look at all the options there. about extending tokens, this one is a bit outdated but should still be true: https://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: Right, that article was in a top answear here on SO. But I defininately get what you're saying. Thank you for the link!